# Can I get rid of the status bar at the bottom of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 3.5 eats up a lot of vertical space with the status bar at the bottom of the window.  To be clear, the status bar says "Writable | Smart Insert | 32:100" right now.

Is there a way I can get rid of it?  Right-clicking doesn't do anything, and there isn't a handle to drag...

Comment: Interesting! These answers don't really fix this problem in a right way. There is no solution (through options, preferences, etc.) as of now! Eclipse fails to do basic UI customization!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a lower vertical resolution monitor, the [Eclipse full-screen plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/) may help you to maximize your work area.

It maximimizes Eclipse to the full screen, hiding the toolbar, the statusbar and (optionally) the menu bar as well (if you know <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd> in Eclipse 3.5 you would not need the menu bar any more :) ).

Comment: This one sounds good, but I think it is rather dead: it has lots of open defects including people offering to help and looking for the source code - all with no response.  Last update is 2008.

Comment: The original project is quite dead but the plugin works well (at least for me in Eclipse 3.7.2 as well). There is a fork however with a new feature and a GitHub repo, see http://ugosan.org/lot-of-space-with-eclipse-fullscreen/

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks.  That's the plug-in referred to in the answer below (GitHub Eclipse full-screen), I believe.   I'll try that one too.

Comment: This plugin (version 1.0.8 from Ugosan) does not seem to work for Eclipse 4.2 on GTK. The title-bar and menu-bar disappears but not the status bar (even if that is checked in the preferences). Anyone have any information about that?

Answer (score 4):

I have used this one successfully with Eclipse Indigo and now Juno.  It gets rid of the title bar at the top of the screen, but not the 'status bar' at the bottom.

Michaels Fullscreen Utility:
http://michaelscharf.blogspot.ca/2009/06/every-pixel-counts-new-eclipse.html

Eclipse Update site:
http://scharf.gr/eclipse/fullscreen/update/

In the Eclipse marketplace:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fullscreen-mode

Source code:
http://eclipse-helpers.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eclipse-helpers/fullscreen-commands/trunk/

Comment: Good update compared to my old answer. +1