# Can't get rid of Eclipse's bottom bar

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint, statusbar

I've already read other threads ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/108668/can-i-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-at-the-bottom-of-eclipse), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645495/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-eclipse)) and installed (rather old) [Fullscreen Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/) but it doesn't hide the fat bottom bar. Is it possible to disable/hide it?
I am using Eclipse 3.7.

[image: this is what I want removed]